why are upgradable packages not upgrading?
I've listed the upgrades by list command and tried to upgrade by using upgrade command but still all the 4 packages are not upgraded.I've attached the command lines below. please help me  as I've no clue what to do now.
apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
distro-info-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.52ubuntu0.7 all [upgradable from: 0.52ubuntu0.6]
python3-update-manager/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.20 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.19]
update-manager-core/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.20 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.19]
update-manager/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.20 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.19]
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  distro-info-data python3-update-manager update-manager update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **4 not upgraded** 

